# Stripe checkout with shipping address

Tags: stripe-payments

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXqzJ.png)I made a stripe checkout with the tutorial from this YT video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mI_-1tbIXQI). Everything works great, except that I want that the customer can also put in his shipping address. Now it is just the email and credit card. It looks like this:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUSCZ.png)

The docs from stripe just say: "You can collect the customer's shipping address in Checkout by setting `shipping_address_collection` when creating the Checkout session." But this doesn't help me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That Youtube video refers to the old/legacy Checkout. You should follow Stripe latest/recommended Checkout: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjcSWxPNo18

The parameter [shipping_address_collection](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_address_collection) is available on the latest Checkout while you create it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

This works in js

```
shipping_address_collection:{
                       allowed_countries:["US"]
            },
```